# Exception handling in R - Return when the right data is downloaded

Tags: r, function, amazon-s3, error-handling

I have the following fields in a dataset.

```
Location : Unique location id of place of installation
Serial : Unique serial number of product
Last Report Date : Date of last communication with location
```

Consider just two locations for now, each with two serials each.

```
Location  Serial LDate       SDate
01        1234   2020-02-29  2020-02-20
01        4321   2020-02-29  2020-02-29
02        2143   2020-03-03  2020-03-03
02        1432   2020-03-03  2020-03-03
```

Here, the last report date of serial is for reference only and is actually not known. I have a dataset with just one serial from each location as below:

```
location serial   SDate
01       1234     2020-02-29
02       1432     2020-03-03
```

In this dataset, the SDate is the latest report date among all the serials at a location.

The data resides in a S3 bucket. The url contains the location and last report date. I am creating the url dynamically to download the data. The url looks like below:

```
url for location 01:"s3://xxxx.xxxx.2020/01/readings/01-20200229.csv"
url for location 02:"s3://xxxx.xxxx.2020/02/readings/02-20200303.csv"
```

I wrote a function to download the data for the serials in my dataset. The logic of the function is as below:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dataset)) {
  date = as.Date(paste0(dataset$SDate[[i]]))
  while (!exists("latest")) {
    latest = s3download(dataset$location[[i]], dataset$serial[[i]], date)
    date = date - 1
  }
  if (!exists("data")) {
    data = latest
    rm(latest)
  }
  else if (exists("data")) {
    data = rbind(data, latest)
    rm(latest)
  }
}
```

The function looks like this:

```
s3download = function(location, serial, date) {
  url = paste0(
    "s3://xxxx.xxxx.",
    lubridate::year(date),
    "/",
    location,
    "/readings/",
    location,
    "-",
    gsub("-", "" , as.character(date)),
    ".csv"
  )
  out = tryCatch({
     latestdata = data.frame(aws.s3::s3read_using(read.csv, object = paste(url), header = FALSE))
  }, error = function(cond) {
    message(cond)
    return(NA)
  }, warning = function(cond) {
    message(cond)
    return(NULL)
  },
  finally = {
    message(paste("Dowloaded))
    message("Thank you")
  })
  return(latestdata)
}
```

The above function is not performing as it should be. The logic is not correct.

What it should be doing is

```
1 Pick the first location and date from dataset
2 Call the function to dynamically create a url with the date
3 Download the data from S3
  a Download the data for the above date for the location
  b See if the data for the desired serial is available
  c If not, repeat steps and b for next dates for this location till data for serial is met
- Repeat step 1:3 for next record in dataset
```

Please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is going wrong? What is the result you see when you expect something else?

Comment: Could you show us the error or 'wrong' result you are getting? Otherwise it's going to be difficult to help you.

Comment: I did some debugging. There appears to be some error with the while statement. I get an error saying "Error in nrow(latest) : object 'latest' not found"

Comment: Solved it. Kept the function simple. Let it return the csv file for the location. Then did a filter on serial. Checked if the dataset has at least one record else called the function again till I got the record.